# Removing ubuntu-desktop through Software Center

Tags: 12.10, software-center

So, I try to delete some applications that I really don't need (Or that I've read reviews and there are better alternatives). But then I got on some applications that tell me "If you uninstall "X Application", future updates will not include new items in the Ubuntu desktop systme set"

What does that mean? It's still safe to delete it?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

Is there anyway to remove the stuff I don't need without messing everything else up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Ubuntu derivative has its own "desktop". For example,

- Unity has the ubuntu-desktop
- Lubuntu has the kubuntu-desktop
- Kubuntu has the kubuntu-desktop and
- Xubuntu has the xubuntu-desktop

Each of these "desktops" is a metapackage, decribed in detail in [MetaPackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages). These metapackages contain nothing but a list of software that give you the corresponding desktop experience. Installing lubuntu-desktop, for example, on Unity, will pull in all the software associated with Lubuntu and afford you the choice of running either Unity or Lubuntu at the time of logging in.

There are times, when, as you have observed, that you want to delete a piece of software for whatever reason and you maybe be warned that doing so will remove  ubuntu-desktop (or some other desktop depending on your environment.)

In fact, Synaptic has this caution regarding the ubuntu-desktop:

> This package depends on all of the packages in the Ubuntu desktop
>   system
>
> It is also used to help ensure proper **upgrades**, so it is recommended
>   that it not be removed.

Based on the Synaptic comment, removing the ubuntu-desktop now *may* be detrimental at some future date.

On the other hand, Synaptic says the same thing about lubuntu-desktop whereas [community documentation on Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveLubuntuDesktop) assures Lubuntu users that there's nothing to fear.

> When you want to remove a program from lubuntu, you may be told that
>   by doing so it will remove lubuntu-desktop. The package
>   lubuntu-desktop is only used for the installation of lubuntu and can
>   safely be removed.
>
> Lubuntu-desktop is what is called a meta-package which, simply put, is
>   just a list of what to install. It is a design decision that all
>   packages included in lubuntu-desktop depend on it, so as to be able to
>   use --no-install-recommends option when the initial installation
>   occurs, thus preventing non-essential programs being installed.
>
> The lubuntu-desktop would just need adding back in for the update from
>   10.04 to 10.10, after that it can be safely removed again.

Even though the quote above refers to 10.04 and 10.10, more recent posts elsewhere have similar opinions. You could look at [[Lubuntu-desktop] lubuntu-desktop metapackage - Recommends vs  Dependencies](http://www.mail-archive.com/lubuntu-desktop@lists.launchpad.net/msg03489.html) and the responses. Again, IMO, even though the desktop being talked about is Lubuntu, the same observations apply to Unity.

In my case, I no longer have lubuntu-desktop because I chose to remove a package of games, aces-of-penguins, and lubuntu-desktop went with it. I must mention that I will be doing a clean install from 12.10 to 13.04 and **not** an upgrade.

Comment: Interesting post. I've deleted some stuff, which like you said (and Ubuntu said too) "If you delete this, everything else will be also deleted". The point is that I don't need some programs, so I deleted them. But then if I want to install X thing woo, everything is installed back. What a pain.

Comment: How and what exactly are you wanting to delete? Whether you use USC, Synaptic, or the command line (apt-get) you'll be informed of what exactly will be done. There's another tool you can use. It's called *simulation*. In other words, you'll just do a dry run without actually installing/removing anything. So, in a terminal, type `apt-get install -s package_name` and hit enter. Then look at the screen output to get an idea. Here, you'll put the actual package name instead of "package_name" and use "remove" or "purge" instead of "install" (if you want to get rid of software).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install the Synaptic package manager and use that.  It give you more granular control for removing packages, as well as more information about what additional dependent packages will also be removed.

Comment: Well yeah, the issue is that after deleting it it deleted the ubuntu-desktop package, which then didn't let me either view photos, create stuff on desktop, etc.