# How to remove unity and unity 2d and install KDE in Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit

Tags: 12.10, kde, desktop-environments

How to remove unity and unity 2d and install KDE in Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit? I want to install the latest KDE.

Answer (score 3):

You must install **kubuntu-desktop** witch installs **KDE desktop** and related packages needed.

do this by

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

You can leave unity by itself if you like, but if you want to remove them, you can totaly remove it by

```
sudo apt-get purge unity unity-2d
```

Answer (score 0):

**KDE options**

There are man ways to install the KDE desktop - the Kubuntu-desktop is the one option. Ubuntu community help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE .

**The latest**

The KDE 4.10 has been backported by the Kubuntu developers. The release information: http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kde-sc-4.10

**Removing a desktop**

The Askubuntu has:

- [How to completely remove desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop)
- [Removing ubuntu-desktop through Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256748/removing-ubuntu-desktop-through-software-center)

Answer (score 0):

Well, another way to "get rid" of Unity completely is to install the Ubuntu Server Edition of your choice, then using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

This will give you Ubuntu, with KDE.

Comment: Why not just directly install Kubuntu?